# Showing something is homeomorphic to $S^2$.

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

> Suppose $X,Y$ are compact surface such that $X\#Y \approx X$ for any compact $X$.  Show that $Y$ is topologically equivalent to the sphere.

I was thinking for a while about this.  It seems pretty obvious that it is a sphere since $X\#S^2\approx X$.  My gut instinct is that the above theorem follows from this fact:

> If $X$ is a compact surface, then $X\approx:$
>   (i)  $nT^2\#S^2$
>   (ii) $nT^2\#K^2$  where $K^2$ is the Klein bottle.
>   (iii) $nT^2\#P^2$ where $P^2$ is the projective plane.

So this means that $X\#Y\approx$ one of those cases.  It also shows that it must be the first case, else $X\#Y \approx X$ won't be true.

Comment: Choose $X = S^2$.

Comment: Then we will have $S^2\#Y\approx S^2$.  Thus $Y\approx S^2$.

Comment: Righty-ho. $\hphantom{foo}$

Comment: Haha I hate how simple this was.

Comment: What does $\#$ mean?

Comment: It means connected sum.

Comment: Okay, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel Fischer pointed out in the comments, one quick way to obtain the solution is to consider $X = S^2$, then it follows immediately that $Y = S^2$.